# ¿Como generar un TimeStamp que dure dias? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firestore

Actualmente puedo generar un timeStamp que dura 60 minutos, igual puedo hacerlo con 24 horas, y utilizo el siguiente metodo para leer la fecha, aqui no ahi ningun problema

```
Long timeStamp = new Date().getTime();`
contenidoExclusivo.setTimeStampLimit(timeStamp + (1000 * 60 * 60)); //60 minutos

public static String timeFormatAMPM(long time, Context ctx) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    if (time < 1000000000000L) {
        // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
        time *= 1000;
    }
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (time > now || time <= 0) {
        String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(time));
        return dateString;
    }
    // TODO: localize
    final long diff = now - time;
    if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(time));
        return dateString;
    } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return "Ayer";
    } else {
        return "Hace " + diff / DAY_MILLIS + " dias";
    }
}
```

el problema es que quiero generar un timeStamp que me dure 5 Dias, algo asi parecido a los estados de WhatsApp que duran 24 horas y luego desaparecen, pero con 5 Dias, lo intente de la siguiente forma pero no me funciona, aqui estoy multiplicando los millisegundo por los segundos por los minutos por las 120 horas que corresponden a los 5 dias, no se si estoy fallando en generar el timeStamp o en el metodo de lectura

```
contenidoExclusivo.setTimeStampLimit(timeStamp + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 120)); //5 dias
```

este es el metodo que utilizo para leer el timeStamp pero no me regresa la fecha correcta, no se si estoy haciendo mal el timeStamp o si es el metodo de lectura en el que estoy fallando, GRACIAS!

```
public static String getFecha (long timeStamp) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp * 1000L);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm: a", calendar).toString();
    return date;
}
```

me regresa la siguiente fecha 26-02-54551 09:09: AM siendo que hoy es 26/7/2022 y me tendria que regresar 31/07/2022 15:33 PM ya que es la fecha actual, solo es un ejemplo

Comment: ¿Cada vez que tengas un `long` enfrente te vas a preguntar si está en expresado en segundos o milisegundos?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, mi problema era que el timeStamp ya venia en Milisegundos, no era necesario convertirlo a milisegundos, en resumen estaba multiplicando * 1000 dos veces, tanto cuando generaba el timeStamp como cuando lo leia mediante el metodo getFecha